# Simple regular expression question (search in VS2008)

Tags: regex

I am trying to change one of the legacy code that declares everything in arrays to a collection. I'd like to do a simple search-and-replace using regular expressions and I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

For example, if arrays are declared this way:

array[0] = "1";
  array[1] = "2";
  array[2] = "3";
  array[3] = "4";
  array[4] = "5";
  array[5] = "6";
  array[6] = "7";
  array[7] = "8";

I would like to grep array[{number}] and replace it with something like list.add(

The regular expression that I am trying to use is array[[0-9]+] but I am getting a syntax error. If anyone could give a helping hand, I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the outer square brackets:

```
array\[[0-9]+\]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to escape your square brackets, as they would normally signify an option group. Use the \ to escape each of your outer square brackets